# I cannot present in Skype for Business

Tags: skype-for-business

Does anyone have any idea why I do not have the present screen option in Skype for Business 2016?

[image]

Comment: Is your machine joined to a domain? If so, are you the administrator? Could be a GPO.

Comment: Glad you worked it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it was a GPO issue, thanks @Patrick_R

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [blog](http://communicationsknowledge.blogspot.com/2016/03/unable-to-share-desktop-in-skype-for.html) which may provide a solution for you.

It is for Skype for business.

Here are some solutions from the [blog](http://communicationsknowledge.blogspot.com/2016/03/unable-to-share-desktop-in-skype-for.html):

> There are multiple thing which may affect application/desktop sharing.
>
> 1. Make sure application / desktop sharing enabled on Skype for Business / Lync Server. SfB /Lync Control Panel > Conferencing >
>      Conferencing policy > select Global or create new policy and set
>      enable ‘Enable application and desktop sharing’. Refer below image.
> 2. Make sure your Skype for Business (Lync) client is updated with latest cumulative updates.
> 3. Update your Video and Display drivers. a.     Go to Start > Control panel. b.     Search for Device Manager, and then open it. c. 
>      Find Video drivers and update the same. d.     Find Display drivers
>      and update the same.
> 4. If in case you are seeing blank screen after application/desktop sharing then do below: Start > Run > Regedit >
>      visit below registry path and delete mentioned key.
>      HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\ActiveX
>      Compatibility\ {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} Note: You must
>      Backed up your computer registry first and then removed above Key.
> 5. Application sharing issue may occurs due to windows firewall blocking Lync.exe communication. Try to stop your windows firewall
>      service and make desktop sharing and test. Start > Run > Services.msc
>
>    > find ‘Windows Firewall’ service and right client on it say Stop.
> 6. Check Application sharing using different test to isolate issue. a.     Is application/desktop sharing affected between internal
>      to internal and external to external? b.     Is application / desktop
>      sharing affected between internal to external to internal and external
>      to internal? Most of the time application sharing issue is tight with
>      firewall. Make sure that you have allowed below port:
>
>    > 1. Allow Any from Internal client to Edge internal over 443/TCP.
>    > 2. Allow Any from Internet to AV Edge external IP over 443/TCP.
>    > 3. Application sharing using TCP port